# Sidekiq using the incorrect url for redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, sidekiq

I'm setting up my Docker environment and trying to get sidekiq to start along with my other services with `docker-compose up`, yet sidekiq is throwing an error in an attempt to connect to the *wrong* redis URL:

```
redis_1    | 1:M 19 Jun 02:04:35.137 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
sidekiq_1  | Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I'm pretty confident that there are no references in my Rails app that would have Sidekiq connecting to localhost instead of the created `redis` service in docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis/data
  sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

And in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` I have hardcoded the redis url:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis:6379/0' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis:6379/0' }
end
```

At this point I'm stumped.  I have completly removed any existing containers ran `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up` multiple times with no change.

I've done a global search within my app folder looking for any remaining references to `127.0.0.1:6379` and `localhost:6379` and get no hits, so I'm not sure why sidekiq is stuck looking for redis on 127.0.0.1 at this point.

Comment: `localhost:6379` is the default configuration sidekiq uses when no other configuration exists. so the question is why sidekiq is ignoring your configuration.. do you have anything else in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` or is that the entire file?

Comment: @eiko That's the entire file contents I provided.

Answer (score 6):

I could not find an explanation for why this is happening. But I did notice this in the sidekiq source code:

```
def determine_redis_provider
  ENV[ENV['REDIS_PROVIDER'] || 'REDIS_URL']
end
```

In the event that `:url` is not defined in `config`, sidekiq looks at the environment variable `REDIS_URL`. You could try setting that to your url for an easy workaround. To make it work with docker, you should simply be able to add `REDIS_URL='redis://redis:6379/0'` to your compose file. Details can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)

Comment: I'll give this a try... do you have a link to reference?  Also, where would be the best place to place this code?

Comment: @Godzilla74 updated my answer with more information and more clarity on how to use the ENV variables.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on... even hard setting the environment variable in `docker-compose.yml`.  I also tried putting the info in a `.env` file a having docker-compose.yml reference that, but still the same error.

Comment: @Godzilla74 at this point, maybe we should start being skeptical about the error message itself. maybe sidekiq *is* hitting your redis server and failing to connect, but the error message is reporting the wrong URL for an unrelated reason. can you check redis logs anywhere to see if there are connections hitting it?

Comment: @eiko You misunderstand the REDIS_PROVIDER variable. It should not be a URL. 
 https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb#L103

Comment: @MikePerham great catch, thank you! i read the code / documentation a bit too quickly.

Comment: @Godzilla74 you should check out my updated question and try changing the environment variable from `REDIS_PROVIDER` to `REDIS_URL`.